# printf("%d") doesn't display what I input

Tags: c, printf

My code:

```
printf("Enter a number : ");

scanf("%d", &number);

printf("%d is what I entered\n", &number);
```

I input `2`,

Expected output : `2 is what I entered`

Actual output : `2293324 is what I entered`

What's the problem here?

Comment: Make a choice C++ or C - two different beasts

Comment: Whenever you input something, you should verify that the input operation was successful, e.g.: `if (1 == scanf("%d", &number)) { ... }`. As was pointed out already, the problem you observed is a different one, though (the use of pointer to the values in `scanf()` and the direct use of values in `printf()`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
printf("%d is what I entered\n", &number);
```

is wrong because `%d`(in the `printf`) expects an argument of type `int`, not `int*`. This invokes [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as seen in the draft (n1570) of the C11 standard *(emphasis mine)*:

> **7.21.6.1 The fprintf function**
>
> [...]
>
> 9. If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. <sup>282)</sup> **If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined**.

Fix it by using

```
printf("%d is what I entered\n", number);
```

---

Then, **Why does `scanf` require `&` before the variable name?**

Keep in mind that when you use `number`, you pass the *value* of the variable `number` and when you use `&number`, you pass the *address* of `number`(`&` is the address-of operator).

So, `scanf` does not need to know the value of `number`. It needs the address of it (an `int*` in this case) in order to write the input into it.

`printf`, on the other hand, does not require the address. It just needs to know the value (`int`, in this case) to be printed. This is why you don't use `&` before the variable name in `printf`.

Comment: Thanks bro, you're a life saver.

Comment: @StevenElcarim It is better to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) instead of commenting "_Thanks!_".

Comment: How is it UB? Won't it will just print the address of the variable instead of its value?

Comment: @HappyCoder "*Won't it will just print the address of the variable instead of its value?*" -- Anything could be the result as the OP's code invokes UB. To print the address, the OP should've used the `%p` format specifier. You need to use the right format specifiers, i.e, you should provide the correct type of variable as the format specifier expects. Otherwise, the code exhibits UB as said in the standard quoted in my answer.

Answer (score 7):

You're using [operator&](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) on `number`, means take address of it, so you're not printing the value of `number`, but the address of it, you should:

```
printf("%d is what I entered\n", number);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you would have used `-Wall -g` compiler option, then you should have seen the error right during compile time:

```
# cc -Wall -g ex.c -o ex
ex.c: In function ‘main’:
ex.c:9:10: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
   printf("%d is what I entered\n", &number);
      ^
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        int number;
        scanf("%d", &number);
        printf("The number is: %d\n", number);

        return 0;
}
```

This should solve your problem.

In `scanf()` first you have to specify what the input item will be(int, float, char, char*, etc...) for your example `"%d"` is for integer.

After that, you have to get the address of your item. That's why you have to use the `&` operator before the variable.

Your error occurred due to the fact that you were using the `&` operator on the `printf()` as well. This basically means that you print the address in the stack where you stored the integer. But without the `&` you print the actual value.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

That `&` operand gives the address of variable "number". You should not use it.
Solution:

```
printf( "%d is what I entered\n", number);
```

Answer (score 0):

u can try removing the & from number and just simply write number

```
printf("%d is what I entered\n", number);
```

Its actually pointing and displaying the memory location of your input ie 2